# how to use the php inside the popup form?

Tags: php, post, isset

I have a e-commerce website.Now I want to configure the payment details.First of all I describe the full details.Below, the image shows choose the payment method.when they choose the cash and click the next button.The page will show our bank account details(these details are shown by isset($_REQUEST['next1']`) but **the request method not working.** These details are shown by popup method.

[image]

```
<fieldset id="fourth">

            <input type="radio" name="cash" id="cash" value="CASH"/>CASH<br />
            <input type="radio" name="card" id="card" value="CARD"/>CARD<br />
            <input type="radio" name="netbanking" id="netbanking" value="NETBANKING"/>NETBANKING

            <input class="pre_btn_bado" type="button" value="Previous">
            <input class="next_btn_bado" name="next1" type="button" value="Next" id="next">


        </fieldset>
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['next1']))
    { 
        $cash = $_POST['cash'];
        $card = $_POST['card'];
        $netbank = $_POST['netbanking'];
        $totalamt = $_POST['rs'];
        $uname = $_POST['name'];

        if($cash == 'cash')
        {
            ?>


    <p>Bank Details</p>

    <p>Bank : ABCD,<br />
                A/C No : xxxxxxx,<br />
                yyyyyyy,<br />
                ABCD Bank,<br />
                aaaaa Branch,<br />
                IFSC : zzzzzzzz

            </p>
            <?php
        }
        elseif($card =='card')
        {
            echo $uname;
            echo $totalamt;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Its not working because you are not submitting a form.

Comment: without submitting a form we can't use isset request method

Comment: Your if code will never execute.

Comment: please suggests any other idea if you know

Comment: Check  my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Bankdetails.php

---

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['next1']))
    { 
        $cash = $_POST['cash'];
        $card = $_POST['card'];
        $netbank = $_POST['netbanking'];
        $totalamt = $_POST['rs'];
        $uname = $_POST['name'];

        if($cash == 'cash')
        {



    echo "<p>Bank Details</p><p>Bank : ABCD,<br />A/C No : xxxxxxx,<br />                   yyyyyyy,<br />ABCD Bank,<br />aaaaa Branch,<br />IFSC : zzzzzzzz               </p>";
           exit;

        }
        elseif($card =='card')
        {
            echo $uname;
            echo $totalamt;
            exit;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

### In your HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#next").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
      url: "Bankdetails.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {next1: "next1"},
      success: function(data){
        $("div").html(data); //Where you want to show the data.
      }
     });
 });
});
```

So basically you need to create a PHP file with bank details and on click of a next button you can send AJAX call and get the details from PHP to show it in your HTML page. Please replace `div` with the ID of div where you want to display the data.

Comment: You can use json_encode and decode to pass and read the data. @Valar